# dnu was always canceled or timeout when restore the vnext mvc demo

Tags: .net, ubuntu, nuget, asp.net-core

I retrive the sample code from https://www.github.com/aspnet/home . when I restore the packages in the latest/HelloMvc folder, The following error occurred:

```
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features'
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Http
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.CommandLine
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Ini
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Framework.Logging
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
----------
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

but I successfully restore at 'lastest/ConsoleApp', then I use wget to download the pacakge with the failed url, there's no problems, I can unzip dlls from that package.

I have restore at 'lastest/HelloMvc' use mono 1.0.0-beta7-12274 runtime, or restore at '1.0.0-beta5/HellowMvc' use 1.0.0-beta5 runtime， or change to use the dockerfile(microsoft/aspnet), even change computer,  the error is the same~

Comment: What mono version are you using?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci   Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Wed Jun 24 10:04:37 UTC 2015) TLS: __thread SIGSEGV: altstack Notifications: epoll Architecture: amd64 Disabled: none Misc: softdebug LLVM: supported, not enabled. GC: sgen

Comment: I am using Mono version 4.3.0 on CentOs 6.6 and I have the same problem.

Comment: I'm having similar problems on OS X. Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c Fri Jul 10 20:47:12 PDT 2015) I'm wondering if it has something to do with the server problems they've been having recently: http://blog.nuget.org/20150608/nuget-server-status.html

Answer (score 5):

did you try to run `mozroots --import --sync`? I've found that solution on https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/184 and it worked for me.

Comment: it doesn't worked for me. but i restore the solution on windows and copy all packages to linux, then restore successful, i think mono-beta7(beta5+) has the bug that cause the request timeout

Answer (score 0):

use following command *env MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000 dnu restore*. This worked for me. You can also set global environment variable, in that case you won't have to type *env MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU* every time you do *dnu restore*.